# Scientific Basis for Apple Watch Activity Rings

Tags: exercise, breathing, technology

I have just started using an apple watch, and am finding that it's "activity rings" feature encourages me to:

1. perform more than 30 minutes of exercise a day (green 'exercise' ring);
2. move around throughout the day to reach a certain calorific value (red 'move' ring);
3. stand and move around for one minute every hour (blue 'stand' ring);

and occasionally,

4. the "breathe" app asks me to take deep breaths for about a minute every 4 hours.

Before giving it so much credence, I was wondering if there was any known scientific basis or consensus for health benefits from doing those things?

Or should I put it in the same category as the folklore about drinking bottled water instead of city water; putting soy milk instead of regular milk in my latte; eating British beef, and re-arranging my furniture to ensure prosperity...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't actually understand what you posted. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there any scientific evidence that there is a health benefit from (1) performing 30 minutes of exercise a day; (2) moving around / burning a certain number of calories a day; (3) standing for one minute every hour; or (4) taking deep breaths for a minute every four hours?  Citations to scientific papers would be helpful.